# select the products not ordered by any employee

Tags: mysql

I want to get the list of `ProductId` which has not been ordered by an `Employee`.

I have this query which gives me all `ProductId` which has been ordered, but I want reverse of it:

```
select distinct e.EmployeeID ,p.ProductID from Products p 
  join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID
 join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
 join Employee e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID order by e.EmployeeID
```

Comment: order by e.EmployeeID desc

Comment: not that order employees who ordered a product and not ordered a product

Comment: Please explain in more details: you need 1st epmployee who is ordered a product, then those who are not?

Comment: list of employee and the products he did not order

Comment: This question is unclear. Please clarify it, including points raised in comments below, or remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Use `left join` and check against `NULL`:

```
select distinct e.EmployeeID ,p.ProductID 
from Products p 
   left join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID
   left join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
   left join Employee e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
where e.EmployeeName IS NULL
order by e.EmployeeID
```

This will return the order details if there is no associated employee record in `Employee` table.

**EDIT:**

Try this one:

```
 select e1.EmployeeID,p1.ProductID
 from Employee e1, p1.ProductID
 where e1.EmployeeID NOT IN
 ( select distinct e.EmployeeID from Products p 
   join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID
   join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
   join Employee e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID)
 and p1.ProductID NOT IN 
 ( select distinct p.ProductID from Products p 
   join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID
   join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID
   join Employee e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID)
```

If you provide some sample data and table structure, we could make a better query.

Comment: its returning nothing

Comment: @srimouni: Please check the tables `orders`,`OrderDetails` and `Employee`, if there is at least one employee who didn't ordered anything.

Comment: yes there are employess who did not order particulat products with product id

Comment: @srimouni: Can you provide some sample data in your question?

Comment: i want only 1 9 to be displayed because employee 1 did not order product with id 9

Comment: 1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 10
1 11
1 12

Comment: @srimouni: See the edit in my answer. Please provide the table structure so that we could give a more simpler query.

Answer (score 0):

try it-

```
select distinct e.EmployeeID ,p.ProductID 
from Products p 
join OrderDetails od on od.ProductID=p.ProductID 
join Orders o on o.OrderID=od.OrderID 
left join Employee e on e.EmployeeID=o.EmployeeID 
where e.EmployeeID is null
order by o.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: If it is not workable for you then either show your sample data and what output you required or create a sqlfiddle..logically this should provide you desired results..

Comment: 1 1
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
1 6
1 7
1 8
1 10
1 11
1 12

Comment: it should display 1 9

Comment: is this a puzzle...:)